# Is there an elegant/simple way to do a Databind on all grids on a page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

Is there an elegant/simple way to do a Databind on all gridviews on a page?
I've inherited some old webform code that has up to 17 gridviews displayed on a page. I need to refresh those views based on new date ranges.

I intend to do a DataBind on the gridviews in the page_load event. This works with the first grid but I don't want to do the same thing 16 more times in the page load event so was wondering is there a way to iterate thru all the gridviews on the page?

All of the gridviews are dynamically being added to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely.

All VISIBILE databound controls whose DataSourceID Property is set will be automatically databound on EVERY Postback and Refresh.

and By Visibile, I mean any Databound Control or Parent of Databound Controls (anywhere up the hierarchy) that have `Visibile=True` will be databound.

Dynamic or otherwise, controls are added to the control hierarchy and they all follow the same rules.

When you build an aspx page all that's going in is you are giving ASP a predefined set of controls and relationships that it builds dynamically on every refresh and postback.

And controls added dynamically from user intervention also follow the same rules, it's just that there is more manual "wiring up" to do but the lifecycle rules still apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the gridview controls like this:-

```
foreach (Control control in Page.Controls)
{
     foreach (GridView grdView in control.Controls.OfType<GridView>())
      {
           grdView.DataSource = data;
           grdView.DataBind();    
      }

 }
```